# Get leaderstats every second while touching part

Tags: roblox

I have been trying to make a code where the player that is touching a part gains leaderstats every second, but for some reason the player is gaining multiple stats every second. And I want the player to stop receiving points when they stop touching the part.

Here is my code:

```
local part = script.Parent
local canGet = true
local function onTouch(otherPart)

    local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid')

    if humanoid then

        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(otherPart.Parent.Name)

        while player and canGet do

            wait(1)

            player.leaderstats.Jump.Value = player.leaderstats.Jump.Value + 1
            


        end

    end

end



part.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```

I just want the player to gain 1 leaderstat per second. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `onTouch` function will be fired multiple times every second. You then create a loop that will run forever multiple times.

One way to implement a solution is to use a debounce variable that blocks the `onTouch` function so it only activates once per second.

I will use your canGet variable as the debounce variable here:

```
local part = script.Parent
local canGet = true
local function onTouch(otherPart)
    if canGet==false then 
       return --If our cooldown is still active, do nothing and stop the function
    end
    local humanoid = otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild('Humanoid')

    if humanoid then

        local player = game.Players:FindFirstChild(otherPart.Parent.Name)

        player.leaderstats.Jump.Value = player.leaderstats.Jump.Value + 1
        canGet = false --We block other executions of the function
        wait(1)
        canGet = true --We waited one second, we can now allow the player to get  more points

    end

end



part.Touched:Connect(onTouch)
```